# How to map two value ranges in tinygo

Tags: go, arduino, microcontroller, tinygo

I'm using Golang to program a arduino uno with tinygo. I am trying to map two value ranges.
One is an encoder with a range between 0-1000 and the other is tinygo's ADC range between 0-65535. I am reading the ADC range and need to covert it to the range of 0-1000 (encoder).

I have tried several things but the basic issue that I'm running into is data types. The below formula for example equals 0:

```
var encoderValue uint16 = 35000
float := float64(1000/65535) * float(encoderValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1000/65535` is an integer division and will result in `0`. It doesn't matter if you convert the result to `float64`, then it'll be `0.0`.

Use floating point constant(s):

```
var encoderValue uint16 = 35000
x := float64(1000.0/65535) * float64(encoderValue)
fmt.Println(x)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/52ke8Z6pKp-)):

```
534.0657663843748
```